# Implementing simpleauth on App Engine - getting 404 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm implementing Simpleauth by Alex on my App Engine (Python 2.7) app: https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth and I can't figure out why I'm getting a 404 error.

When I try to go to '/profile' when not logged in, I get properly re-directed to '/'.  But when I log in (successfully) and get directed to '/profile' I get a 404.

I assume this is because it hits the "TemplateNotFound" exception in the 'render' code.  But the "profile.html" file exists and is properly in the 'templates' directory.

**Could anyone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?**

Here is the code on the relevant files:

**app.yaml**

```
handlers:
- url: /auth/*
  script: main.app
- url: /profile
  script: main.app
- url: /logout/*
  script: main.app
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

**main.py**

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
from secrets import SESSION_KEY

template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.getcwd()))

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = template_env.get_template('templates/home.html')
        context = {
        }
        self.response.out.write(template.render(context))

app_config = {
  'webapp2_extras.sessions': {
    'cookie_name': '_simpleauth_sess',
    'secret_key': SESSION_KEY
  },
  'webapp2_extras.auth': {
    'user_attributes': []
  }
}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
    webapp2.Route('/profile', handler='handlers.ProfileHandler', name='profile'),
    webapp2.Route('/auth/<provider>', handler='handlers.AuthHandler:_simple_auth', name='auth_login'),
    webapp2.Route('/auth/<provider>/callback', handler='handlers.AuthHandler:_auth_callback', name='auth_callback'),
    webapp2.Route('/logout', handler='handlers.AuthHandler:logout', name='logout')], config=app_config, debug=True)
```

**handlers.py**  (unchanged from Alex's Simpleauth code!)

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import auth, sessions, jinja2
from jinja2.runtime import TemplateNotFound

from simpleauth import SimpleAuthHandler

class BaseRequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def dispatch(self):
    # Get a session store for this request.
    self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

    try:
      # Dispatch the request.
      webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
    finally:
      # Save all sessions.
      self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

  @webapp2.cached_property    
  def jinja2(self):
    """Returns a Jinja2 renderer cached in the app registry"""
    return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

  @webapp2.cached_property
  def session(self):
    """Returns a session using the default cookie key"""
    return self.session_store.get_session()

  @webapp2.cached_property
  def auth(self):
      return auth.get_auth()

  @webapp2.cached_property
  def current_user(self):
    """Returns currently logged in user"""
    user_dict = self.auth.get_user_by_session()
    return self.auth.store.user_model.get_by_id(user_dict['user_id'])

  @webapp2.cached_property
  def logged_in(self):
    """Returns true if a user is currently logged in, false otherwise"""
    return self.auth.get_user_by_session() is not None


  def render(self, template_name, template_vars={}):
    # Preset values for the template
    values = {
      'url_for'    : self.uri_for,
      'logged_in'  : self.logged_in
    }

    # Add manually supplied template values
    values.update(template_vars)

    # read the template or 404.html
    try:
      self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(template_name, **values))
    except TemplateNotFound:
      self.abort(404)

  def head(self, *args):
    """Head is used by Twitter. If not there the tweet button shows 0"""
    pass


class ProfileHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    """Handles GET /profile"""    
    if self.logged_in:
      self.render('profile.html', {
        'user': self.current_user, 
        'session': self.auth.get_user_by_session()
      })
    else:
      self.redirect('/')
```

Comment: What does it say in the logs? Also, in your question you say that the "profile.html" file exists, but main.py has the filename as "home.html" (see line 9) - is this right?

Comment: I use Jinja2 like App Engine describes here (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates) but the handlers.py SimpleAuth uses it differently.  In the rest of the app I import jinja2 and set the Environment template, but in simpleauth it imports jinja2 from webapp2_extras and then sets a cached property in the BaseRequestHandler. I'm not sure how to unwrap these two ways of approaching it.

Comment: Jed, try removing try/catch from the render() method so that if there's any exception it'll bubble up and you'll see it in the logs. I'm pretty sure you're right - it's something within the profile.html or a base template.

Comment: Okay, when I do that I get a TemplateNotFound error.  I've got to sort out how I set the Jinja2 environment, which means I've got a bunch of re-writing in front of me!  Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem above is that I was using two different ways of implementing Jinja2.  The two different methods are discussed in a separate question: [Which is the preferred method to use jinja2 on App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022030/which-is-the-preferred-method-to-use-jinja2-on-app-engine)

It was the mixing and matching that was causing the 404 error.